# How to update & append a value to a many-to-many sequelize implementation

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have this 2 models describing 2 tables i need to perform api operations to :

```js
// USER MODEL
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            User.belongsToMany(models.Company, {
                through: 'UserCompany',
                foreignKey: 'id',
            })
        }
    };
    User.init({
        firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
        phone: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
    });
    return User;
};

// COMPANY MODEL
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Company extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            Company.belongsToMany(models.User, {
                through: 'UserCompany',
                foreignKey: 'id',
            })
        }
    };
    Company.init({
        company_name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Company',
    });
    return Company;
};
```

I'd like to be able to add users to companies, and add companies to users. Hence the many-to-many / `belongsToMany` implementation here. For exemple, in my company controller, to fetch a company, I do :

```js
    getById(req, res) {
        return Company
            .findByPk(req.params.id, {
                include: [{
                    model: User,
                    as: 'users'
                }],
            })
            .then((company) => {
                if (!company) {
                    return res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'Company Not Found',
                    });
                }
                return res.status(200).send(user);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                res.status(400).send(error);
            });
    }
```

How am I supposed to :

- Add a user to a company ?
- Add a company to a user ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

sequelize sets special [methods/mixins](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances) on models which helps you to handle the counterpart of your created model

```js
const account = await Account.create({ myAccountProps });

await account.setCompanies(arrayOfCompanies);
```